# What is the difference between 'Temporary files' and 'Cache'?

Tags: cache, temporary-files

Is there any difference between *Cache files* and *Temporary files*? If so what? And what do each term mean?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking caches (using files... or otherwise) are for storing data locally, so that when needed again access is faster than retrieving the data again from wherever they came. Cache files can remain even after the program using them is not running anymore.

Temporary files can be used for cache, but also for other things (that are not caching), like for example the undo data for a (imaging, spreadshet, ...) program, sometimes also communication between processes. As the name indicates, these files are (normally) removed when the program using them no longer needs them.

If you are referring to "temporary *internet* files", then yes in this specific case it is cache, and the files are not so temporary.